# How to fix size for drop down menu with css

Tags: html, css

I need these two drop down menus to be a fixed size and not auto resized depending on their content text length. hown can I make it so that its a fixed size but then when clicked it would resize so that the longer words in the list also show without a  horizontal scroll bar

Comment: You want the drop downs to change widths when clicked, but at a "fixed" width by default? Is a Javascript solution acceptable?

Comment: @jullian. n. i'm using a tool with limited functionality

Comment: @user521180 What 'tool'? You list the "web-development" tag. What browser/device are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

To set sizes on cross-client interfaces I simply parse the list and add an option to the list with a line of all 0's [zeros]. By adding or deleting zeros from that line you can get a uniform size on your selects lists for all browsers, font size and type dependent of course. After the document loads have javascript remove the select list option with the zeros and you are left with a static width select list.

Example:

```
<select>
    <option value="SIZER">0000000000000000000000000000</option>
</select>
```